# Blazor event after dom renders

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I'm using the `OnAfterRender()` method which works well, however it fires long before controls are actually rendered on the screen.

I want an event that fires when the screen is available for user interaction.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have child components inside your main component?

Comment: I don't have any Blazor components if that's what you mean.  Just normal HTML controls.  They render about 3 or 4 seconds after the OnAfterRender() event fires.